# How to sort a text file based on a string and search

Tags: c, string, sorting, search, structure

I'm new to this forum and also new to C program. I don't have a good knowledge about string and structure, and I'm having trouble doing the following task: The first task is to sort a text file by data in a string. The second task is to search by information in a specific string and display all the information related to that string on the screen. This is my structure

```
struct element{
    char id[20];
    char name[20];
    char address[20];
}profile;
```

I removed the part which asks user to input data and stores it in a file. Now how can I sort the data by id (I don't know how to get the number of elements in that string) and how to search by name or address and after that display the related information on the screen. Thanks for reading and sorry if my question sounds stupid.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you show us your attempted solution?

Comment: I haven't found any proper solution so far..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now how can I sort the data by id

With a sort. Since this smells like homework, you may or may not be allowed to use the venerable `qsort` function.

> (I don't know how to get the number of elements in that string)

`strlen`

> and how to search by name or address

Try using functions such as `strcmp` to compare strings.

Comment: You are right, this is my homework and I'm allowed to use any method. Since I didn't pay much attention to the teacher at the class I'm struggling to do it right now :( Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Well, it sound like that you should have paid more attention in class.